# How do I send Segmented Control variable to prepareforsegue?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I make sure I send `selectedFocus` to my next view controller in prepareForSeque? (or assign a variable based on what portion of the segmented control button in prepareForSeque?) `"Use of unresolved identifier 'segmentedControlVariable"` is my error.

```
class SecondSignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    // DECLARATIONS...

    // user's focus to be sent to next view contr.
    var selectedFocus = String()

    // 1. LOAD IN SENT VARS (so that it exists in this view) (at top it seems oposed to in viewdidload?...)
    var passedPassword_toView2:String!
    var passedUsername_toView2:String!
    var passedEmail_toView2:String!

    @IBAction func continueButtonPressed2(sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueAfterJoin2", sender: self)
    }



@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        print("case0")
        textLabel.text = "You are a music artist who needs services.";
        imageShown.image = image0
        selectedFocus = "artist"
    case 1:
        print("case1")
        textLabel.text = "You want to share your talent with music artists.";
        imageShown.image = image1
        selectedFocus = "provider"
    default:
        break; 
    }
}

// VAR SHIFT 
// GET FROM PREV. VIEW
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("view 2 loaded")

    // 2. (for ease,) TRANSFER TO VAR NAMES
    var myLocalPassword = passedPassword_toView2
    var myLocalUsername = passedUsername_toView2
    var myLocalEmail = passedEmail_toView2

}

// 3. SEND VARS TO NEW VIEW
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "SegueAfterJoin2") {
        var nextViewCont = segue!.destinationViewController as! ThirdSignUpViewController;

        // PASS VARS FROM THIS VIEW TO NEXT
        nextViewCont.passedPassword_toView3 = passedPassword_toView2
        nextViewCont.passedEmail_toView3 = passedUsername_toView2
        nextViewCont.passedUsername_toView3 = passedEmail_toView2

        //how can I toss this in too?
        nextViewCont.passedFocus_toView3 = selectedfocus

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing now? Cant you pass the selectedFocus to nextViewCont just like you pass other toView2 vars?

Comment: Yes I'm not sure how to approach this

Comment: "Use of unresolved identifier 'segmentedControlVariable'" is the error I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your thirdviewcontroller are you created the `passedFocus_toView3` variable

do like

on your first view controller called this

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "YourSegueName") {
        //get a reference to the destination view controller
        let destinationVC:ViewControllerClass = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerClass

        //set properties on the destination view controller
        destinationVC.passedFocus_toView3 = selectedfocus
        //etc...
    }
}
```